# Stains in the bathroom

Tags: bathroom, walls, paint, stain, paint-removal

We have some stains in our bathroom with shower.
We already painted our bathroom 2 times by ourselves and 1 time was professionally painted with primer and then with paint.
After 2 months, when professional painter finished this job, the stains have started to appear again.
Could you please help us with your advice, how we can remove these stains? What are they? And how can I remove these stains?

[image]   [image]

[image]     [image]

Comment: Is that water ? where does it comes from, was the paint made for wet surfaces >

Comment: Not meldew, someone is squirting hair coloring

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not hair coloring.  the number of these spots is growing.  bleach doesn't help.

Comment: Have you tried vinegar or lemon juice?  Also, what is the relative humidity?  Do you have a window or exhaust fan to dry the bathroom a bit quicker after a shower?  How does it smell?

Comment: i have tried bleach, vinegar, nothing helps. they reappear. we do not shower in this bathroom. there is a window that open al  the time. These stains do not smell. they appeared first on the walls, and then on the door, it is wooden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bathroom. Looks like mildew.

- Bleach will kill the mildew.
- Then spot-prime with white pigmented
  shellac, like Kilz.
- Then ask your local paint store to mix up some
  paint with an anti-fungal ingredient for damp environments.
- If they
  don't know what you're talking about, find another paint store.

Comment: Not mildew, not on the door

Comment: Thank you very much. 
I have already used bleach.  they reappear in a week.  these spots are getting bigger and bigger. the number of these spots is growing.  I would like to ask you to send a photo of paint.

Comment: If they come back like that after a week, I would get a mold test kit and see how that responds.  If you kill it all and it comes right back, it has to be coming from somewhere.  It doesn't look like the typical bathroom mold I'm used to seeing.  I assume that is a plastic door, which really shouldn't be attracting much mold/mildew.

Comment: @Ruskes, you're claiming it isn't mildew on the door, based on the photo? Looks like mildew to me!